# How to split an email on @ symbol and display in two table cells?

Tags: php, html, email, delimiter, tablecell

I want to display the values separately which I got through `explode()`.  But the problem is that my table shows me two values which are exactly same. I don't know the reason behind it and thoroughly searched on the StackOverflow, but couldn't find my answer.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Domain Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $str = "naveen.dharni@gmail.com";
                    $hello = explode("@",$str);
                    foreach ($hello as $value)
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$hello[0]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$hello[1]</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `$value` and not `$hello[0]`

Comment: You have a loop over the data array and then in every iteration print all array contents again. Either use the loop or just remove the loop and use your 4 echo statements directly.

Comment: Converting the string to an array and then back to a string is overkill, just keep it as a string and prepare it with a single function call -- no extra variables and no foreach loop needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($hello as $value)
{
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Basically you need to set TR tag before the foreach.

Secondly in `foreach`,  the `$value` contains both values in iterations so do not need to print `$hello[0]`.

Just print `$value`

Answer (score 1):

after you explode there are two value which is before `@` and after `@`, that is why you are printing your value twice

try this

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Domain Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $str = "naveen.dharni@gmail.com";
                $hello = explode("@",$str);
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$hello[0]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$hello[1]</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: please check the code carefully, it is inside one `<tr></tr>` so it will display in single row

Answer (score 1):

Your loop displays each part of your array you get from `explode()`. Within your loop you use `$hello`,  wich is the array itself.

You need to echo the actual `$value` like this:

```
 echo "<tr>";

 foreach ($hello as $value) {
      echo "<td>$value</td>";
 }

 echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr><td>";
foreach ($hello as $value)
{       
   echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Value is each part of the array.
So each time the loop goes, the $value changes.

EDIT; it seems you want the email parts in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, just implode the values:

```
$str = "naveen.dharni@gmail.com";
$hello = explode("@",$str);
echo '<tr><td>',implode('</td><td>',$hello),'</td></tr>';
```

or even simpler, replace the @ sign with `</td><td>`

```
$str = "naveen.dharni@gmail.com";
echo '<tr><td>',str_replace('@','</td><td>',$str),'</td></tr>';
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e88c768f41f53c59223d606d8631437f6d687ea8)